# Scala - a type-parametrized trait method returning a type-parametrized object - how to implement?

Tags: scala, types, implementation, type-systems, traits

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
trait Entity {
  type E <: Entity
  type S <: Something[E]
  def in: S
}

trait Something[E <: Entity] {
  def doSomething {
    // something
  }
}

class A extends Entity {
  def in = InA
  object InA extends Something[A]
}
class B extends Entity {
  def in = InB
  object InB extends Something[B]
}
class C extends Entity {
  def in = InC
  object InC extends Something[C]
}
```

and somewhere else I want to:

```
val entities = Seq[Entity]
entities.map(_.in.doSomething)
```

however, the type system does not let me get away with that `in` method definition - I just can't figure out what types should I specify there for the piece of code to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you override the type members like this. Scala does not infer them automatically.

```
class A extends Entity {
  type E = A
  type S = Something[A]
  def in = InA
  object InA extends Something[A]
}
class B extends Entity {
  type E = B
  type S = Something[B]
  def in = InB
  object InB extends Something[B]
}
class C extends Entity {
  type E = C
  type S = Something[C]
  def in = InC
  object InC extends Something[C]
}
```

Another option would be to do away with type members and only use type parameters.

```
trait Entity[E <: Entity[E]] {
  def in: Something[E]
}

trait Something[E <: Entity[E]] {
  def doSomething {
    // something
  }
}

class A extends Entity[A] {
  def in = InA
  object InA extends Something[A]
}
class B extends Entity[B] {
  def in = InB
  object InB extends Something[B]
}
class C extends Entity[C] {
  def in = InC
  object InC extends Something[C]
}

val entities = Seq[Entity[_]]()
entities.map(_.in.doSomething)
```

This uses a technique called [F-bounded polymorphism](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded).

Comment: The second variant impairs the ability to map from, say a `Seq[String]` to get a `Seq[HasForm]` because it cannot infer the type parameters... is there another trick for that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you give an example? Do you mean mapping from a `Seq[Entity[A]]` to a `Seq[Entity[B]]`?

Comment: Please disregard that comment, there was no problem, it was my mistake. Thank you for the answer!